# Knockoutjs multiple dropdown from single array

Tags: knockout.js

```
var dropdownData = [
   {City: "New York City", State:"New York" },
   {City: "Albany", State:"New York" },
   {City: "Bufflo", State:"New York" },
   {City: "Rochester", State:"New York" },
   {City: "San Francisco", State:"California" },
   {City: "Los Angeles", State:"California" },
   {City: "San Diego", State:"California" }
];
```

I would like to display two drop down list where first dropdown list displays all new york cities and the second dropdown with list of california cities. Can somebody please shed some light no how to accomplish it in knockoutjs? the "dropdownData" list is dynamic, so that if additional states getting added to the list, the dropdown should be generated dynamically.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add two dependentObservables that return filtered views of your array (which you should convert to an observableArray anyway). One would be just the unique values for state (you could use ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues for this) and the other would be the cities corresponding to the selected state (use ko.utils.arrayFilter). See [here](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html) to get you started.

Comment: Thanks Matt! Actually I got it working with static list, since the list is dynamic, I just want drop down list for each state in the array. Thanks for the input, it certainly helps!